# Let me show you how to viewport Compositing in real time! (Blender 3.3.1)

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, compositing-nodes

A lot of people still don't know how to enable real time composting, this is because it's not that intuitive to do. Today I'm gonna explain it really simple for newbies and experienced users, just as it is!

1. *Open a new tab* and switch to "**Compositing**" (or just switch from the current one).
2. *The tab will probably be empty*, this is because you have to click on "**Use Nodes**" checkbox on the top right screen.
3. After this, you will see a "**Render Layers**" node connected to "*Composite*" node. The composite node is like the output material node. Now we need to put an other node called "Viewer", this will allow us to preview the compositing, setting the image as background of the compositing tab
4. You still don't see anything? It's because you need to enable the "Backdrop", it's on the top right corner of the compositing tab, and then you will need to render at least one image, which is the image that will be set as backdrop.

If you see just a white X with a black background make sure that the viewer node is actually present.
Anything you put into the **Viewer** node should be put into the **Composite** too in order to be rendered with the edits you've made!

Now you know too! :)

Comment: Hello and welcome! Thank you for your contribution! However, I would ask you to follow the format given here, and always formulate a clear question first. If you wish to provide the answer to your question yourself, post in the answer section afterwards. Please make these changes, otherwise I would have to close this "question" immediately. Thank you for your understanding.

Comment: And by the way, and I hope this doesn't disappoint you too much now: The answer to the underlying question has already been given here several times: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=compositing+viewer Exactly for this there is a search function here, with which you can find an answer relatively easily. I'll let you rephrase the question, and hope that the content differs from the existing answers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. While answering your own question is possible and even encouraged, it should be done respecting the site structure. Could you break this up into two posts, rephrasing the problem to read like an actual question or expose a problem, while the solution is written as separate answer in the proper section below? Maybe add a short description of the steps accompanied by a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)